# Better to use task dependencies or task.doLast in Gradle?

Tags: gradle, build.gradle

After building my final output file with Gradle I want to do 2 things. Update a local version.properties file and copy the final output final to some specific directory for archiving. Let's assume I already have 2 methods implemented that do exactly what I just described, `updateVersionProperties()` and `archiveOutputFile()`.

I'm know wondering what's the best way to do this...

Alternative A:

```
assembleRelease.doLast {
    updateVersionProperties()
    archiveOutputFile()
}
```

Alternative B:

```
task myBuildTask(dependsOn: assembleRelease) << {
    updateVersionProperties()
    archiveOutputFile()
}
```

And here I would call **myBuildTask** instead of **assembleRelease** as in alternative A.

Which one is the recommended way of doing this and why? Is there any advantage of one over the other? Would like some clarification please... :)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Whenever you can, model new activities as separate tasks. (In your case, you might add *two* more tasks.) This has many advantages:

- Better feedback as to which activity is currently executing or failed
- Ability to declare task inputs and outputs (reaping all benefits that come from this)
- Ability to reuse existing task types
- More possibilities for Gradle to execute tasks in parallel
- Etc.

Sometimes it isn't easily possible to model an activity as a separate task. (One example is when it's necessary to post-process the outputs of an existing task in-place. Doing this in a separate task would result in the original task never being `up-to-date` on subsequent runs.) Only then the activity should be attached to an existing task with `doLast`.

Comment: How do you recommend to create those tasks dependencies? I would like a single task to assemble the whole project (basically "replacing" `assembleRelease`) and both of those tasks must be executed only **after a successful** execution of `assembleRelease`. Between them, the order is not really relevant.

Comment: `myBuildTask.dependsOn(updateVersionProperties, archiveOutputFile); updateVersionProperties.dependsOn(assembleRelease); archiveOutputFile.dependsOn(assembleRelease)`