# After update to Android Studio 2.2 / gradle plugin 2.2.0: "could not get unknown property 'assembleRelease'"

Tags: android, gradle, android-studio-2.2

After updating **Android Studio** to **version 2.2** and the **Gradle-plugin** to **2.2.0**, I get following error:

**"Could not get unknown property 'assembleRelease' for project ':app' of type org.gradle.api.Project."**

When I change the plugin version back to *2.1.3* the code still works, but that's no long-term option for me.

**My code:**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

dependencies {
...
}

android {
...
}

...    
assembleRelease.doLast {
  file('build/outputs/apk/app-release.apk').renameTo("AppName-1.0.0-${project.ext.androidVersionCode}.apk")
}
```

***Hint:***
project.ext.androidVersionCode is a variable defined otherwhere and contains a build number. The code in assembleRelease.doLast shall just move/rename the generated apk file.

Thank you for advices!
tangens

Comment: Could you provide more code?

Comment: I made some changes to make it clearer what I want to do.

Comment: Take a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/38569576/2652124
To find the task you can use the Find in Path option, as the answer's comment says.

Comment: Thank you for this hint, but it does not resolve my problem.
But it's helpful, though.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You may rewrite your task a bit and try like this:

```
task renameBuildTask() << {
  file('build/outputs/apk/app-release.apk').renameTo("AppName-1.0.0-${project.ext.androidVersionCode}.apk")
  dependsOn 'assembleRelease'
}
```

Also you can check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17438219/better-to-use-task-dependencies-or-task-dolast-in-gradle) question to get better understanding.

**EDIT**

As @tangens said in a comment:

> It works when I replace the call gradle assemble by e.g. gradle renameBuildTask. Thank you! The answer contains an error. Correct would be: task renameBuildTask() << { ... }

Comment: It works when I replace the call *gradle assemble* by e.g. *gradle renameBuildTask*.
Thank you!

The answer contains an error. Correct would be:
`task renameBuildTask() << {
...
}`

Comment: Where do you put this, in **app**'s build.gradle file?  I am getting an error: `No signature of method java.lang.String.dependsOn() is applicable for argument types`

Answer (score 16):

```
tasks.whenTaskAdded { task ->
  if (task.name == 'assembleRelease') {
    task.finalizedBy 'yourRenameTasks'
  }
}
```

Comment: Where do you put this - in the **app** module, or top-level project directory?

Comment: @IgorGanapolsky app module

Comment: It doesn't do anything for me when pressing the green Run button.

Comment: tasks.whenTaskAdded { task ->
            if (task.name == 'assembleDebug') {
                task.dependsOn 'setEnvDebug'
            } else if (task.name == 'assembleRelease') {
                task.dependsOn 'setEnvRelease'
            }
        }

Answer (score 7):

maybe wrap code in afterEvaluate{} will be work:

```
afterEvaluate {
    assembleRelease.doLast {
       file('build/outputs/apk/app-release.apk').renameTo("AppName-1.0.0-${project.ext.androidVersionCode}.apk")
    }
}
```

gradle-2.14.1 and android gradle plugin 2.2.0

details:
[Could not get unknown property 'assembleDebug' (2.2-beta)](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=219732)

Answer (score 5):

I had the same problem after upgrading Android Studio to 2.2 and Gradle to 2.2.
I have task copyApk that needs to be run at the end of building. For brevity, let me skip what was working before, and post only what is working right now:

```
tasks.create(name: 'copyApk', type: Copy) {
    from 'build/outputs/apk/myapp-official-release.apk'
    into '.../mobile'
    rename('myapp-official-release.apk', 'myapp.apk')
}

tasks.whenTaskAdded { task ->
    if (task.name == 'assembleRelease') {
        task.dependsOn 'copyApk'
    }
}
```

Gradle console shows copyApk was run near the end after packageOfficialRelease, assembleOfficialRelease, right before the last task assembleRelease.  "Official" is a flavor of the app.
I got the workaround from [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39642141/assembledebug-dependson-not-working). I essentially copied the answer  here for your convenience. All credits go to the author of that post.

Comment: Which gradle file do you put these tasks into?

Comment: In the app's build.gradle.

Answer (score 0):

you can do this:

```
task copyApk(dependsOn: "assembleRelease") << {
    file('build/outputs/apk/app-release.apk').renameTo("AppName-1.0.0-${project.ext.androidVersionCode}.apk")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

inside buildTypes {} method, I put this code : worked like a charm

```
task setEnvRelease << {
            ant.propertyfile(
                    file: "src/main/assets/build.properties") {
                entry(key: "EO_WS_DEPLOY_ADDR", value: "http://PRODUCTION IP")
            }
        }

        task setEnvDebug << {
            ant.propertyfile(
                    file: "src/main/assets/build.properties") {
                entry(key: "EO_WS_DEPLOY_ADDR", value: "http://DEBUG IP TEST")
            }
        }
tasks.whenTaskAdded { task ->
            if (task.name == 'assembleDebug') {
                task.dependsOn 'setEnvDebug'
            } else if (task.name == 'assembleRelease') {
                task.dependsOn 'setEnvRelease'
            }
        }
```