# Gradle extend assembleRelease

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

on gradle 2.1.3 I could do:

```
assembleRelease
{
    doFirst()
    {
    //some code
    }
}
```

But when I updated to gradle 2.2.0 I get an error:

```
Error:(12, 1) A problem occurred evaluating project ':MyProj'.
> Could not find method assembleRelease() for arguments [build_6dlppzyvvovwra7h55acb4kp$_run_closure1@543a3981] on project ':MyProj' of type org.gradle.api.Project.
```

Can you please help me with that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems to be a common issue for version update to 2.2.0. You can find some similar questions on SO, [for example here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39602587/could-not-get-unknown-property-assemblerelease-for-project). But they all lead to a common workaround - rewrite your task this way:

```
tasks.whenTaskAdded { task ->
    if (task.name == 'assembleRelease') {
        task.doFirst {
            //some code
        }
    }
}
```

Not sure, but it seems, that `assembleRelease` is not available at the moment you try to point it in your script since 2.2.0 version.